# pathos.multiprocessing raised 'Interrupted system call' message

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, fork

I have written a code that uses multiprocessing. I posted the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382111/using-multiprocessing-in-a-class). Now the code is working perfectly and I got the final results even the last part of plotting is done but with an error message at the end:

```
Exception OSError: (4, 'Interrupted system call') in <Finalize object, dead> ignored
```

I have no idea why this error message occurred. Could anybody explain it?

Comment: Looks like you're using `pathos.multiprocessing`, not `multiprocessing`. You should make that clear in the questions/tags.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238349/python-multiprocessing-exit-error ?